# ImageMagick convert resize by the smaller dimension?

Tags: imagemagick

The following command resizes the larger dimension to 256:

```
convert -resize 256x256 in.jpg out.jpg
```

For example, if `in.jpg` is 1024x512, it resizes it to 256x128.

Is it possible to resize the smaller dimension to 256 (while keeping the aspect ratio) with ImageMagick `convert`? (I need 512x256)

If not, is there any other easy command line solution?

Comment: Huh? The command already resizes to 256 and maintains the aspect ratio. Can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just added an example

Comment: Do you mean `convert in.jpg -resize x256 out.jpg`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [fill area flag ^](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#fill) seems to do exactly what you want:

```
convert -resize 256x256^ in.jpg out.jpg
```

If you're on Windows:

> The Fill Area Flag ('^' flag) is a special character in Window batch scripts and you will need to escape that character by doubling it. For example '^^', or it will not work.

This only works with ImageMagick 6.3.8-3 and above. For older versions, use [this trick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#space_fill).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the command I suggested in my comment will work, namely

```
convert in.jpg -resize x256 out.jpg
```

Or, if you actually want to identify the smaller dimension and resize that explicitly, this should do the trick

```
#!/bin/bash
image=$1
cmd="x256"
[ $(identify -format "%[fx:w<h?1:0]" "$image") -eq 1 ] && cmd="256x"
convert "$image" -resize $cmd out.jpg
```

I preset the command to resize by height at line 3. Then I ask ImageMagick to output `1` if the image is taller than wide, and if it is, I change the resize command to resize by width. Then, finally, I do the actual resize. You can re-cast the script various ways to make it shorter, or leave it explicit.

E.g.

```
if [ $(identify -format "%[fx:w<h?1:0]" in.jpg) -eq 1 ]; then 
   convert in.jpg -resize x256 out.jpg; 
else 
   convert in.jpg -resize 256x out.jpg; 
fi
```